# Converting a char * to string *

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to convert a char pointer to a string pointer but I am not sure if I am doing it correctly. I just wanted to post what I was trying and see if it was correct.

For context, I have a char * called ent->d_name and I need that to become a string *.
This is what I have been doing:

```
std::string arg = std::string(ent->d_name);
std::string * arg_p = &arg;
Command::_currentCommand->insertArgument(arg_p);
```

The insert command function takes a string pointer.

Comment: There is rarely any reason to use a `string *`. If you are using a library that does so, the person who designed the library almost certainly didn't know what they were doing, and you should not be using that library. And you cannot directly convert a `char *` to a `string *`.

Comment: It is for my school project. I do not like it either, but I do not have a choice.

Comment: Whether this is correct or not depends on what this `Command` thingie is going to do with `arg_p`. Does it just use it right away or does it store it somewhere? Is it guaranteed that `arg` does not get destroyed before the `Command` accesses the pointer you gave it?

Comment: You should probably take a step back and explain why you think you need a `string*`. It's more likely you want a `string`, and probably want to create a new one instead fo casting...

Comment: It is going to store the argument in a vector of string pointers. It will end up using it.

Comment: Well, what you have to make sure is that the `string` that the pointer you hand over to the `Command` points to is still alive when the `Command` accesses the `string`. If `arg` is destroyed while `Command` still has a pointer to `arg` in its vector of pointers, that pointer will be dangling and if `Command` ever accesses it, you get undefined behavior…

Comment: A string pointer is usually a bad idea, so a vector of string pointers is N bad ideas.

Comment: I get what you're saying but that doesn't really answer the question. I am still unsure how to convert it.

Comment: @Darren - The term "convert" is ambiguous. There are few direct ways to  convert a `char *` to a `std::string *`, and most subsequent uses of the `std::string *` will have undefined behaviour. Less direct means (e.g. create a `std::string` from the `char *` and obtain its address) are possible, but depend on what the `char *` points at (e.g. does it point to a nul terminated `char` array?) and on what subsequent code does with the `std::string *`. In your case, what `command::_currentCommand->insertArgument()` does with its argument matters. Nobody can really help unless you explain all that.

Comment: @Darren *This is what I have been doing:* -- Even if you were doing that, there is no need for the pointer. `std::string arg = std::string(ent->d_name); Command::_currentCommand->insertArgument(&arg);` -- Why the intermediate pointer variable, when you could have just passed the address of `arg`?

Comment: Just wanted to come back and explain why we're using string pointers because I've figured it out. Regular string objects would be on the stack, but we want the arguments to live until the end execution, so we put them on the heap. That means we have to store pointers to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
std::string *arg_p = new std::string(ent->d_name);
```

It will create a memory leak unless you `delete` each string after use, but apart from that it will work.